# VBA Access - Show queries results in subform for each element in another subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

Right now I've a Subform1 (SFUCOM) which lists a mixed variety of codes of machines and sets from a same Order-Content (U-COM) table filtered by selecting an Order from a combobox. Clicking on each of these shown codes (Me.ctrlSUB) a second Subform2 (SFUMCH) lists these machines/sets content (parts) and other things through this onclick event:

```
Private Sub ctrlSUB_Click()

Dim SQLMCH As String
Dim SQLRSN As String
Dim SQLSET As String
Dim SQLOTH As String
      
SQLMCH = "SELECT [U-MCH].IDSUB, [U-MCH].Qty, LNK.Allegato " _
       & "FROM LNK RIGHT JOIN [U-MCH] ON LNK.IDREC = [U-MCH].IDSUB " _
       & "WHERE ((([U-MCH].IDSUP) ALike '%" & Me.ctrlSUB.Text & "%') AND ((LNK.IDREC)=[U-MCH].[IDSUB]))"
       
SQLRSN = "SELECT [U-RSN].IDSUB, [U-RSN].Qty, LNK.Allegato " _
       & "FROM LNK RIGHT JOIN [U-RSN] ON LNK.IDREC = [U-RSN].IDSUB " _
       & "WHERE ((([U-RSN].IDSUP) ALike '%" & Me.ctrlSUB.Text & "%') AND ((LNK.IDREC)=[U-RSN].[IDSUB]))"
       
SQLSET = "SELECT [U-SET].IDSUB, [U-SET].Qty, LNK.Allegato " _
       & "FROM LNK RIGHT JOIN [U-SET] ON LNK.IDREC = [U-SET].IDSUB " _
       & "WHERE ((([U-SET].IDSUP) ALike '%" & Me.ctrlSUB.Text & "%') AND ((LNK.IDREC)=[U-SET].[IDSUB]))"

SQLOTH = "SELECT [U-COM].IDSUB, [U-COM].Qty, LNK.Allegato " _
       & "FROM LNK RIGHT JOIN [U-COM] ON LNK.IDREC = [U-COM].IDSUB " _
       & "WHERE (((LNK.IDREC) ALike '%" & Me.ctrlSUB.Text & "%'))"
          
 If (Left(Me.ctrlSUB.Text, 3) = "MCH") Then
   Forms![Q-COM]!SFUMCH.Form.RecordSource = SQLMCH

ElseIf (Left(Me.ctrlSUB.Text, 3) = "RSN") Then 
   Forms![Q-COM]!SFUMCH.Form.RecordSource = SQLRSN
   
ElseIf (Left(Me.ctrlSUB.Text, 3) = "SET%") Then
   Forms![Q-COM]!SFUMCH.Form.RecordSource = SQLSET
   
Else
   Forms![Q-COM]!SFUMCH.Form.RecordSource = SQLOTH
   
 End If
   
   Forms![Q-COM]!SFUMCH.Form.Requery


End Sub
```

And it works like a charm, simply love it.

Now the PAINFUL PART: I would really like to have in Subform1 a button in order to list in Subform2 ALL the parts of ALL Machines/Sets/etc. listed in Subform1. I've already found a looks-like-working-solution to avoid all of these IF...ELSEIF... with a single dynamic query, something like this:

```
Dim codTAB As String
Dim SQLGOD As String
Dim extcod As String

 If (Left(Me.ctrlSUB.Value, 3) = "MCH") Then
  codTAB = "[U-MCH]"
 ElseIf (Left(Me.ctrlSUB.Value, 3) = "RSN") Then
  codTAB = "[U-RSN]"
 ElseIf (Left(Me.ctrlSUB.Value, 3) = "SET") Then
  codTAB = "[U-SET]"
 Else
  codTAB = "[U-COM]"

End If
    
SQLGOD = "SELECT  (" & codTAB & "." & "IDSUB" & "), (" & codTAB & "." & Qty & "), LNK.Allegato " _
       & "FROM LNK RIGHT JOIN (" & codTAB & ") ON LNK.IDREC = (" & codTAB & "." & "IDSUB" & ") " _
       & "WHERE (((" & codTAB & "." & "IDSUP" & ") ALike '%" & Me.ctrlSUB.Text & "%') " _
       & " AND ((LNK.IDREC)= (" & codTAB & "." & "IDSUB" & ")))"
       
   Forms![Q-COM]!SFUMCH.Form.RecordSource = SQLGOD
   Forms![Q-COM]!SFUMCH.Form.Requery
```

But I'm honestly all over the place on how to set the recordsource as a sort of "union" of all the results for each of the records in Subform1.

Any feedback or suggestion is more than welcome

---

EDIT AND ADDITIONAL INFOS:
There are 4 different tables U-COM, U-MCH, U-RSN, AND U-SET because an order contain in U-COM MCH/RSN/SET and spare parts, U-MCH/U-RSN/U-SET contain loose parts, sort of matrioska. Something like this:

```
[U_COM]
Order    IDSUP   | [U_MCH]/RSN/SET
Content  IDSUB  -> IDSUP            |  [LNK]
         Qty     | IDSUB    Parts  ->  IDREC
                  Qty              |  Allegato (attachment/Linked filepaths)
```

So Subform1 (SFUCOM) has as recordsource U-COM filtered by the Order combobox, while Subform2 (SUMCH) has as recordsource the first code (ctrlSUB_Click)

Comment: Why are there 4 tables with same structure? A UNION will result in non-editable dataset.

Comment: There is missing information about both queries structures so I will only point you in the right direction.  Subqueries/forms are bound by linked fields to main queries/forms.  Instead think of queries 1&2 as two different result sets you want to show/hide in two different(!) forms. Save queries 1 and 2 as either saved queries or strings.  Create those two forms at design time so you can see the result of each query in its form when finished.  next drag the new forms onto the main form and edit the main forms buttons to show and hide the new forms

Comment: The 4 tables have only some fields in common, the others are not shown in this form. I've edited this post trying to be clearer, adding infos and I'm already sorry for the mess it